# jQuery slider does not work on mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, slider

I am new JQuery developer! I created a simple **jQuery slider**. It works on desktop browsers , but not work on mobile.
When I click on **next** and **pre** the image should change! On mobile the page reloaded and never show next image

*My Jquery App*

```
$('#n').click(function(){
        var displayedImg = '';
        $('img').each(function(){
            if($(this).css('display') == 'inline'){
                displayedImg = $(this);
            }
        }); // end of each
        if(displayedImg.attr('title') == 1) {
            displayedImg.toggleClass("SS");
            $("img").eq(1).toggleClass("SS");
        } else if (displayedImg.attr('title') == 2) {
            displayedImg.toggleClass("SS");
            $("img").eq(2).toggleClass("SS");
        } else if  (displayedImg.attr('title') == 3){
            displayedImg.toggleClass("SS");
            $("img").eq(0).toggleClass("SS");

        } 

    });

    $('#p').click(function(){
        var displayedImg = '';
        $('img').each(function(){
            if($(this).css('display') == 'inline'){
                displayedImg = $(this);

            }
        }); // end of each

        if(displayedImg.attr('title') == 1) {
            displayedImg.toggleClass("SS");
            $("img").eq(2).toggleClass("SS");
        } else if (displayedImg.attr('title') == 2) {
            displayedImg.toggleClass("SS");
            $("img").eq(0).toggleClass("SS");
        } else if  (displayedImg.attr('title') == 3){
            displayedImg.toggleClass("SS");
            $("img").eq(1).toggleClass("SS");   
        }
    });
```

*HTML*

```
        <img src='0.jpg' style="width:300px" title="1">
        <img src='1.jpg' style="width:300px" class="SS" title="2">
        <img src='2.jpg' style="width:300px" class="SS" title="3"><br />
        <a id='p' href="#">pre</a>
        <a id='n' href="#">next</a><br />
```

I uploaded this code on my host http://sete.ir/en/

**UPDATE**

I am using chrome 40 , Android 4.2.2 on lenovo A300

Comment: Works for me on mobile. Chrome Beta, android.

Comment: I am using chrome 40 , Android 4.2.2 on lenovo A300 and does not work :|